# Didn't set position ActionBar Logo with NavigationDrawer android

Tags: android, android-actionbar, navigation-drawer

I m using navigation drawer and want to put a launcher icon to the right of navigation drawer icon and put a title on right of launcher icon in `ActionBar`. I m trying this but didn't get the expected result.

**Image here :**

[image]

I m using

```
actionbar.setLogo(imageId); //to set the launchericon
actionbar.setTitle("home"); //to set the title
```

but the problem is, didn't able to set the launcher icon position in `ActionBar`.

please help me out.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Attach your actionBar image with your question , that  you want to achieve

Comment: i have added a image url in starting PFA in that my logo is in center and i want to fix the position for it.

Comment: @AmanGoyal post an image so that we can understand what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I answered your question , Please check , if any issue reply me @AmanGoyal

Comment: @nimi0112 i don't have access to load images on stackOverflow. So Pls understand it if possible.Thanks

Comment: @Abhishek Thanks, i have already done this part but the issue is launcher icon is located in center and i want to change position and shift this to the immediate right of navigation drawer icon without any space.

Comment: @AmanGoyal search for any images and post it's link here.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you mean to say that your toolbar logo is not getting displayed for a custom toolbar. A possible workaround for that would be to an `<ImageView>` to your custom toolbar itself and set the image.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimary">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/my_custom_icon"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_custom"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Custom Title"
        android:id="@+id/custom_title"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/menu_icon"/>
</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Note that you could also add the `android:centerHorizontal="true"` to the textview if you want the title to be in center. Next declare the toolbar and call the textview in the required file by the id

```
TextView customTitle = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.custom_title);
customTitle.setText("My Custom Title");
```

Instead of using the `getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);` we have defined it in the xml. Now use this code in the java.

```
ImageView cumstomIcon = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.my_custom_icon);
customIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.some_image);
```

You can also directly set the image in the xml but if you need to keep diff. images for various activities, then set the image programmatically..
Any doubts drop a comment!

Comment: Thanks for the reply but i m using this with navigationDrawer, so i need a navigation drawer icon, the logo and the title dislayed on the actionbar at the same time. Is it work in that situation?

Comment: it will work perfectly. Give a try and drop a comment if issue still persists.

Comment: Check the updated code. Define that in your onCreate in java.

Comment: Select the correct answer and upvote. Or post the correct solution. It could help the future android enthusiasts who wish to learn or get stuck up similar. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use below code to set `logo` and `title` on your **ActionBar** :

**RESULT / OUTPUT :**

[image]

**CODE:**

```
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");
```

**FULL CODE :**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //Here is the code
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);


    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setLogo(R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Home");


    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
```